# How does git reset <filename> work?

Tags: git, addition, reset, staging

There are 2 statements about `git reset` that are true but I find them contradictory given my limited knowledge of how Git works.

Is there a way to reconcile the 2 statements?

Statement 1:
`Git reset file1` will un-add *file1* from the staging area.

This is the command to use when you added *file1* to staging and you changed your mind and want to remove it from the staging area.

Statement 2:
`Git reset file1` will copy files from HEAD to the staging area.

According to statement 2, `git reset` *adds* files to the staging area.

So how do the files become removed from the staging area when they were just copied to it from HEAD?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're reading those two statements, but the description in [the `git-reset` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) seems clear.

Answer (score 2):

HEAD refers to the head of the current branch, i.e. the newest commit. When you change a file, the file in your working copy differs from HEAD. Staging that difference means copying the file from the working copy into the staging area.

Unstaging means removing a difference against the HEAD from the staging area. Hence unstaging is done by copying the state from HEAD back into staging area.

Comment: Ok, so it's about removing the difference, rather than removing the file. So before I add a modified tracked file to the staging area, it's already there? It stays there from the last commit?

Comment: When committing a change, the staging area is written to a tree in the repository and a commit is created that references that new tree. After that the staging area just stays as it is, so yes, the state remains from the last commit.

Comment: Additionally, changing the HEAD (i.e. by switching branches using git checkout) can be thought of as first updating the index to the state of that commit (see [git read-tree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree)) and then applying any differences to the working copy (see [git checkout-index](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout-index)). So in this case the staging area also contains the state of the latest commit.

Answer (score 0):

**How does git reset  work?**

Lets take an example :-

We added **octodog.txt** into our family **octofamily**

```
git add octofamily/octodog.txtcode
```

So now that **octodog** is part of the family, **octocat** (our previous file) is all depressed.

Since we love **octocat** more than **octodog**, we'll turn his frown around by **removing octodog.txt**

You can unstage files by using the git reset command. Go ahead and remove octofamily/octodog.txt.

```
git reset octofamily/octodog.txt
```

git reset did a great job of unstaging **octodog.txt**, but you'll notice that he's still there. He's just not staged anymore. It would be great if we could go back to how things were before octodog came around and ruined the party.

**Files can be changed back to how they were at the last commit by using the command:**

`git checkout -- <target>`

Go ahead and get rid of all the changes since the last commit for **octocat.txt**

```
git checkout -- octocat.txt
```

for further reference and git knowledge [here is one git game](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1)

hope it will clear your all git related doubt's :)